# Get specially added price attribute in front end

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have added retail price attribute in magneto back-end as price type.It showing in back-end.
I'm considering normal price as rental price.So i want to calculate the percentage difference between rental and retail.So i tried to get the rental price in front end product listing page.but doesn't work.

method 1:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->load($_product->getId())
     ->getAttributeText('retail_price');
```

method 2:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('retail_price');
```

both does n't work.but "manufacturer" works

```
$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Whats wrong. How can i do this.Help me

Comment: Hey gowri, have you check the property of this new product attribute?. Is this value visible, editable? Is the linkage between the tables comlete. Maybe you'll find out more by loging the getAttributeText function. Good Luck!

Comment: Because of the setter/getter capabilities, can't you just do `$_product->getRetailPrice()`?

Comment: Look at the webpage, maybe it can be help you:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/

Comment: @danny:yes it's visible in front end listing and product pages.how can i see the logging of getAttributeText function.

Comment: @BrianVPS:what's the setter/getter capabilities . how can i solve this.

Comment: Magento is built using PHP's special setter/getter capabilities.  Let's say you grab a product like this:  `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123);`  Now that you have your product, if you want to grab an attribute of that product, you can simply use `$product->getAttributeName();` where **AttributeName** is the TitleCase version of the the attribute code, in this case **attribute_name**.  You basically split the code at the '_', captialize each word, and add "get" in front of it and you have your special getter method.

Comment: You can log the results you're getting back in the `getAttribute`-function by using: `Mage::log('result');` The log-messages can be viewed in `/var/log/system.log `. But one more question, is the attribute available/visible in the product collection? Best way to check that, is to `print_r` or `var_dump` your collection/$product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
$_product->getRetail_price();
```

In listing page, use:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('your_attr_code');
```

Comment: thank you. works in view.phtml ! but how about product list.phtml?? seems not to work there

Comment: @nicmare:check my edit.use your attribute code in getAttributeText function.Be conscious about your object $_product is the same one used for others